# How can I install the proper GPU driver for radeon 5450 on Debian Jessie?

Tags: debian, drivers, graphics, amd-graphics

I have a monitor that supports 2560x1080. While I have a Radeon 5450 graphic card, running Debian Jessie, I only can get 1920x1080. I installed `firmware-linux-nonfree` to get it running. **Why isn't my complete resolution listed?**

**Installing fglrx-driver using apt-get**

I have to mention that `sudo apt-get install fglrx-driver` gives me the following error:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx-driver 
[sudo] password for mostafa: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 fglrx-driver : Depends: xorg-video-abi-19 but it is not installable or
                         xorg-video-abi-18 or
                         xorg-video-abi-15 but it is not installable or
                         xorg-video-abi-14 but it is not installable or
                         xorg-video-abi-13 but it is not installable or
                         xorg-video-abi-12 but it is not installable or
                         xorg-video-abi-11 but it is not installable or
                         xorg-video-abi-10 but it is not installable or
                         xorg-video-abi-8 but it is not installable or
                         xorg-video-abi-6.0 but it is not installable
                Recommends: fglrx-modules-dkms (= 1:15.9-4~deb8u2) but it is not going to be installed or
                            fglrx-kernel-15.9
                Recommends: libgl1-fglrx-glx (= 1:15.9-4~deb8u2) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libgl1-fglrx-glx-i386 but it is not installable
                Recommends: fglrx-atieventsd but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**Insalling proprietary driver from AMD website**

And installing proprietary driver from AMD website ends with the following error:

```
Supported adapter detected.
Check if system has the tools required for installation.
Uninstalling any previously installed drivers.
Unloading radeon module...
rmmod: ERROR: Module radeon is in use
Unloading drm module...
rmmod: ERROR: Module drm is in use by: ttm drm_kms_helper radeon
[Message] Kernel Module : Trying to install a precompiled kernel module.
[Message] Kernel Module : Precompiled kernel module version mismatched.
[Message] Kernel Module : Found kernel module build environment, generating kernel module now.
AMD kernel module generator version 2.1
doing Makefile based build for kernel 2.6.x and higher
rm -rf *.c *.h *.o *.ko *.a .??* *.symvers
make -C /lib/modules/4.5.0-2-amd64/build SUBDIRS=/lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.5.0-2-amd64'
  CC [M]  /lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/firegl_public.o
/lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/firegl_public.c: In function ‘firegl_major_proc_read’:
/lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/firegl_public.c:634:9: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
     len = seq_printf(m, "%d\n", major);
         ^
/lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/firegl_public.c: In function ‘KCL_fpu_save_init’:
/lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/firegl_public.c:6458:49: error: ‘XSTATE_FP’ undeclared (first use in this function)
       if (!(fpu->state.xsave.header.xfeatures & XSTATE_FP))
                                                 ^
/lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/firegl_public.c:6458:49: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/firegl_public.c: At top level:
/lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/firegl_public.c:6448:12: warning: ‘KCL_fpu_save_init’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int KCL_fpu_save_init(struct task_struct *tsk)
            ^
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.5.0-2-common/scripts/Makefile.build:263: recipe for target '/lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/firegl_public.o' failed
make[4]: *** [/lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x/firegl_public.o] Error 1
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.5.0-2-common/Makefile:1408: recipe for target '_module_/lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x' failed
make[3]: *** [_module_/lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/2.6.x] Error 2
Makefile:146: recipe for target 'sub-make' failed
make[2]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.5.0-2-amd64'
Makefile:88: recipe for target 'kmod_build' failed
make: *** [kmod_build] Error 2
build failed with return value 2
[Error] Kernel Module : Failed to compile kernel module - please consult readme.
[Reboot] Kernel Module : update-initramfs
```

Comment: Does the `radeon` driver not work? See https://wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo for details...

Comment: I tested it right now, no results.

Answer (score 0):

According to [debian-wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/ATIProprietary) you need to install `linux-headers` and `fglrx-modules-dkms`

First add the following line to your `sources.list`:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```

Then type the following command:

```
aptitude update
aptitude -r install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') fglrx-driver
```

Create the confugration file `20-fglrx.conf`

```
mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
echo -e 'Section "Device"\n\tIdentifier "My GPU"\n\tDriver "fglrx"\nEndSection' > /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-fglrx.conf
```

Reboot and verify your résolutions.

Comment: Installing fglrx-modules-dkms gives me the same errors from insalling proprietary driver from AMD website